# C++ - Type mismatch error when initialising static private class member

Tags: c++

I have a class that I would like to be able to statically generate random instances of itself. To do this I have a static instance of `std::uniform_real_distribution`. However, I am getting a type mismatch error in the compiler.

The compiler errors are: `'genId' in 'class Foo' does not name a type` and `'randId' in 'class Foo' does not name a type`. However, I have specified the type in the header file as can be seen below.

The header file (Foo.hpp):

```
class Foo {
public:
    static std::random_device rdId;
    static std::mt19937 genId;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> randId;
    // other code
}
```

The implementation file (Foo.cpp):

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

Foo::genId = std::mt19937(Foo::rdId());
Foo::randId = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, 100);
// other code
```

Why does this error occur when I have already declared the type?

Comment: You need to specify the type in the implementation file, too

Comment: @DanielJour am wondering why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type:

```
std::mt19937 Foo::genId = std::mt19937(Foo::rdId());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> Foo::randId = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks @tuple_cat, is there any specific reason why I need to specify the type when I have already declared it in the header and 'regular' members don't need their type to be reiterated when they are initialised?